# Android System.out.println() only prints a portion of my string with length 86521 bytes

Tags: android, html, system.out

I have a webpage in html/string form saved into pageContent java String. This file is 86531 bytes long.

When i print this string via system.out.println() it only prints a portion of the string.

When i print this string via Log.d() it won't print at all.

When I copy the contents of string in debugger via "copy value" and paste it into note ad I see that the entire HTML page content is being copied over.

How do I print the contents of pageContent and pass it as an argument to another function?

Is it because since the HTML page is so large that it is filling up the local stack and that's why nothing is printed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Indeed,it should be because of filling up the stack.

If you are using Android studio, then the only way to change the limit is to set `idea.cycle.buffer.size` value in `idea.properties`.